# How to test / work with github pull requests locally?

Tags: python, git, scipy, pull-request

I reported in [BUG: scipy.optimize.minimize() does not report lowest energy visited. #15089](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/15089)  a bug in scipy.

Until now this resulted in a [pull request MAINT: ScalarFunction remember best_x #15099](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/15099) , which is presently not incorporated in a new scipy release.

I would like to work with this pull request locally, as I do not want to wait until it gets incorporated in a new scipy release.

Yesterday I cloned [scipy](https://github.com/scipy/scipy), fetched the pull request and installed it locally editable:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git
cd scipy/
git fetch origin pull/15099/head:ScalarFunction-remember-best_x
source ~/venv/numba38/bin/activate
pip install -e .
```

Now I am facing an error when I execute the referring functionality of scipy.
Before asking the scipy people what is going on, I would like to know whether I did my first pull request testing correctly.

pip freeze shows:

```sh
pip freeze|grep scipy
-e git+https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git@1474e4c4f7a934d2390fbc259def0ba2cc3526a1#egg=scipy
```

In Pycharm I can see:

```
Package   Version                              Latest version
scipy     1.9.0.dev0+1073.1474e4c              1.7.3
```

My questions:

1. did I do everything correct to expect that this pull request would work isolatedly?

if not:

2. would I have to clone instead from the scipy release that was already published at the time of the pull request creation?
3. would I have to incorporate other (which?, all?) pull requests before starting to test?

Comment: 1. Everything you did is right, 2 and 3 aren't required. But there is something you didn't do (or at least not showed us): after `git fetch` there should be `checkout` or `merge` or `rebase` so that the code from the branch `ScalarFunction-remember-best_x` appeared in the current branch and the working tree; then `pip install` will install it. `git checkout ScalarFunction-remember-best_x` is certainly the 1st thing to try.

Comment: Normally each pull request should work in isolation; when you fetched it, you got all the code that went into the code base at that point in time. (In theory, the maintainer could have committed non-working code, but that would hardly be the expectation here.)

Comment: @phd: thanks for your advice. If I realized it correctly, somehow the pull request was active even without your hint. But still even after `git checkout ScalarFunction-remember-best_x` the bug in the pull request prevailed. Therefore it seems to be an issue in the pull request and I therefore commented it in the pull request in github (I expect that creating a new issue in github is not the way to do it... )

@tripleee: thanks for your comment, too!